# what is the difference between $||T_nx|| $ and $||T_n|| ?$

Tags: functional-analysis

In the uniform Boundedness theorem  it is  written  $||T_nx|| \le c_x$ and $||T_n|| \le c$

My confusion : what is the difference between $||T_nx|| $ and $||T_n||? $

My thinking : In real analysis  we take $f_n(x)=f_n$ so here im confusing that

Are both $||T_nx|| $ and $||T_n|| $ are same?

Comment: $f_n(x) = f_n$ is not true. One is a real number, the other is a function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are not the same. $\|T_n\|$ is the operator norm of $T_n$, but $\|T_n x\|$ is the norm of the specific vector $T_n(x)$, where $x$ is an element of the domain of $T_n$.

Answer (score 2):

$\|T_n\|=\sup_{\|x\|\leq 1} \|T_n(x)\|$

of some $T_n$.

$\|T_n x\|$ is the norm of the image $T_n(x)$.

Answer (score 1):

In other words, the statement $\| T_n x \| \le c_x$ reads
$$
\forall \ x \in E \quad \exists \ c \ge 0 \quad \forall \ n \in \mathbb{N} \quad \| T_n x \| \le c,
$$
while the statement $\| T_n \| \le c$ is equivalent to
$$
\exists \ c \ge 0 \quad \forall \ x \in E \quad \forall \ n \in \mathbb{N} \quad \| T_n x \| \le c.
$$
The latter is obviously stronger. However, Banach-Steinhaus theorem shows they are actually equivalent if $E$ is a Banach space.

And of course, $\| \cdot \|$ here means two different things, as Ben Grossmann pointed out.